# Would multiple SPFx webparts on page load duplicate dependencies?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, webpack

If I have an SPFx webpart and that webpart uses these dependencies:

- jQuery
- jQueryUI
- Angular
- LoDash

Then I have another SPFx webpart and that one uses:

- jQuery
- jQueryUI
- React
- Moment

If I load both those webparts on my page, I would be loading two bundles on the page. But both bundles have `jQuery` and `jQueryUI`. Is that not inefficient and could it cause conflicts?

I assume it's not going to cause a conflict but I'm concerned about loading duplicate libraries in terms of network consumption. I understand it's minified and likely cached through a CDN but still, not very DRY.

Comment: helpful? https://blog.mastykarz.nl/bundling-external-frameworks-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-bad-idea/

Comment: Yea it does. So essentially don't bundle external dependencies because of what I stated above, unless you really need to or can't use a CDN. Sounds good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right - you don't want to make those libraries bundled internally.  You want them to be referenced externally.